# Service clause failed

Tags: sparql, allegrograph

I am trying to query different repositories in allegrograph using sparql service clause but I am getting service clause failed error, could anyone let me know what am I doing wrong.

I think it has something to do with the endpoint.

This is my sample query:

```
query_string = """PREFIX ab: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#> 
PREFIX d:  <http://learningsparql.com/ns/data#>    

SELECT  ?first 
WHERE{
   
  service  <http://localhost:10035/repositories/repo1/> {
  ?s ab:firstName ?first. }

         
}"""
```

error : Server returned 400: Canceling query because a SERVICE clause failed.

Comment: Do you have a SPARQL server running on `localhost:10035`?

Comment: I think yes, I am using sparqlwrapper library

Comment: do I need to install jena fuseki for that?, because with graphdb service clause works perfectly fine but not with allegrograph